# Tracing Journaled fileSystem

Tags: python, filesystems, operating-system

How can we trace changes going in journal of journaled filesystem like ext3/4.
Being more specific, would like to capture information of read and writes on disk using info in journal.

Will appreciate if there's a way using python.

Comment: I am naive for stackoverflow, could you make your point more clear ?

Comment: visit your profile on http://stackoverflow.com/users/162463/varunvyas, then visit the questions you have already asked. If the questions have answers, that you think meet your question and are useful, mark them (as you did with my answer below). This will let other visitors know that the question has an acceptable answer and will also reward the answerer with +15 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) is what you are looking for?